# Append/show html in div as it is

Tags: jquery, html, append

I want to append text/html tags in div without changing its meaning.
So when I append 
`<a>This is not anchor </a>`, 
should display `<a>This is not anchor </a>`
But it displays hyperlink inside div --> This is not anchor .

How can i achieve this using `$("#mydiv").append("<a>This is not anchor</a>").`
Please help.

Comment: Read up on HTML entities. Especially `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to append it as text itself. then use like this,

```
$("#mydiv").text($("#mydiv").text()+"<a>This is not anchor</a>")
```

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` appends content as html and not as text. whereas you need to append the content as text. you can use callback function of `.text()` to achieve this:

```
$("#mydiv").text(function(i,o){
  return o + "<a>This is not anchor</a>"; 
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ekjvxx2/)**